# RSA Encryption-Decryption : BadPaddingException : Data must start with zero

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm sorry to ask your skills about a question asked so many times.
I have an issue about RSA crypthography.
I've already checked the other topics about this issue but i didn't find any helpful answer.
I hope you'll be able to help me.

I want to read a file, crypt its contain and then decrypt it and put these decrypted bytes in a new file.

I actually can :
- get the bytes of a file
- crypt it

I have the exception : javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero.

Here is my code :

```
    package com.bodom.ghosty;

    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.security.*;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class EncryptionUtil {
        private final PrivateKey privateKey;
        private final PublicKey publicKey;

        /**
         * Build an EncryptionUtil object
         *
         * @param keyPair The KeyPair used for Ghosty
         */
        public EncryptionUtil (KeyPair keyPair) {
            this.privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            this.publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        }


        /**
         * Generate a pair of RSA keys
         *
         * @return A keypair of RSA keys
         * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
         */
        private static KeyPair keyGenerate() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyGen.initialize(2048);
            return keyGen.genKeyPair();
        }


        /**
         * Crypt data
         *
         * @param data      Data to encrypt
         * @return          The crypted data
         * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
         * @throws NoSuchPaddingException
         * @throws InvalidKeyException
         * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
         * @throws BadPaddingException
         */
        private static byte[] rsaEncryption(byte[] data, EncryptionUtil encryptionUtil) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptionUtil.publicKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(data);
        }


        /**
         * Read the bytes of a file
         *
         * @param file is the file to read
         * @return     the bytes of the file
         * @throws IOException
         */
        private static byte[] readBytesInFile (Path file) throws IOException {
            byte[] result = new byte[(int)Files.size(file)];
            try {
                try (InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getFileName().toString()))) {
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while (bytesRead < result.length) {
                        int bytesLeft = result.length - bytesRead;
                        int bytesGet = inputStream.read(result, bytesRead, bytesLeft);
                        if (bytesGet > 0) {
                            bytesRead += bytesGet;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            return result;
        }


        /**
         * Encrypt a file
         *
         * @param file      Path of the file to crypt
         * @return          A byte array which contains the crypted lines of the file
         * @throws java.io.IOException
         * @throws javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
         * @throws java.security.InvalidKeyException
         * @throws javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
         * @throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
         * @throws javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException
         */
        public static byte[] encryption (Path file, EncryptionUtil encryptionUtil) throws IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
            byte[] datatocrypt = readBytesInFile(file);
            int offset = 0;
            byte[] cryptedfile = null;

            while (offset < datatocrypt.length) {
                byte[] outputBytes;
                byte[] tmp;

                if(datatocrypt.length - offset < 200 ) {
                    outputBytes = new byte[datatocrypt.length - offset];
                    System.arraycopy(datatocrypt, offset, outputBytes, 0, datatocrypt.length - offset);

                    byte[] crypt = rsaEncryption(outputBytes, encryptionUtil);

                    tmp = cryptedfile;
                    if (tmp != null) {
                        cryptedfile = new byte[tmp.length + crypt.length];
                    }
                    else cryptedfile = new byte[crypt.length];

                    if (tmp != null) {
                        System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, cryptedfile, 0, tmp.length);
                        System.arraycopy(crypt, 0, cryptedfile, tmp.length, crypt.length);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.arraycopy(crypt, 0, cryptedfile, 0, crypt.length);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                outputBytes = new byte[200];
                System.arraycopy(datatocrypt, offset, outputBytes, 0, 200);

                byte[] crypt = rsaEncryption(outputBytes, encryptionUtil);

                tmp = cryptedfile;
                if (tmp != null) {
                    cryptedfile = new byte[tmp.length + crypt.length];
                }
                else cryptedfile = new byte[crypt.length];

                if (tmp != null) {
                    System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, cryptedfile, 0, tmp.length);
                    System.arraycopy(crypt, 0, cryptedfile, tmp.length, crypt.length);
                }
                else {
                    System.arraycopy(crypt, 0, cryptedfile, 0, crypt.length);
                }

                offset += 200 ;
            }
            return cryptedfile;
        }


        /**
         * Decrypt data
         *
         * @param crypteddata Crypted data to decrypt
         * @return            The decrypted data
         * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
         * @throws NoSuchPaddingException
         * @throws InvalidKeyException
         * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
         * @throws BadPaddingException
         */
        private static byte[] rsaDecryption(byte[] crypteddata, EncryptionUtil encryptionUtil) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, encryptionUtil.privateKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(crypteddata);
        }


        /**
         * Decrypt a file
         *
         * @param file       Path of the file to decrypt
         * @return           A byte array which contains the decrypted lines of the file
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
         * @throws InvalidKeyException
         * @throws BadPaddingException
         * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
         * @throws NoSuchPaddingException
         */
        public static byte[] decryption(Path file, EncryptionUtil encryptionUtil) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException {
            byte[] crypteddata = readBytesInFile(file);
            int offset = 0;
            byte[] decryptedfile = null;

            while (offset < crypteddata.length) {
                byte[] outputBytes;
                byte[] tmp;

                if(crypteddata.length - offset < 200 ) {
                    outputBytes = new byte[crypteddata.length - offset];
                    System.arraycopy(crypteddata, offset, outputBytes, 0, crypteddata.length - offset);

                    byte[] decrypt = rsaDecryption(outputBytes, encryptionUtil);

                    tmp = decryptedfile;
                    if (tmp != null) {
                        decryptedfile = new byte[tmp.length + decrypt.length];
                    }
                    else decryptedfile = new byte[decrypt.length];

                    if (tmp != null) {
                        System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, decryptedfile, 0, tmp.length);
                        System.arraycopy(decrypt, 0, decryptedfile, tmp.length, decrypt.length);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.arraycopy(decrypt, 0, decryptedfile, 0, decrypt.length);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                outputBytes = new byte[200];
                System.arraycopy(crypteddata, offset, outputBytes, 0, 200);

                byte[] decrypt = rsaDecryption(outputBytes, encryptionUtil);

                tmp = decryptedfile;
                if (tmp != null) {
                    decryptedfile = new byte[decrypt.length + tmp.length];
                }
                else decryptedfile = new byte[decrypt.length];

                if (tmp != null) {
                    System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, decryptedfile, 0, tmp.length);
                    System.arraycopy(decrypt, 0, decryptedfile, tmp.length, decrypt.length);
                }
                else {
                    System.arraycopy(decrypt, 0, decryptedfile, 0, decrypt.length);
                }
                offset +=200 ;
            }
            return decryptedfile;
        }

        /**
         * Save a key in a file
         *
         * @param modulus  Modulus of the key to save
         * @param exponent Exponent of the key to save
         * @param filename File used to save the keys
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
         */
        private static void saveKeyToFile (BigInteger modulus, BigInteger exponent, String filename) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            Path path = Paths.get(filename);
            if(!Files.exists(path)) {
                Files.createFile(path);
            }

            try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))) {
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(modulus);
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(exponent);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Save a KeyPair in two files
         *
         * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
         * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
         * @throws FileNotFoundException
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public static void saveKeyPair(EncryptionUtil encryptionUtil, String directorypath) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

            RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(encryptionUtil.publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
            saveKeyToFile(rsaPublicKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPublicKeySpec.getPublicExponent(), directorypath + "/public.key");

            RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivateKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(encryptionUtil.privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);
            saveKeyToFile(rsaPrivateKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPrivateKeySpec.getPrivateExponent(), directorypath + "/private.key");
        }

        /**
         * Get a PublicKey from a file
         *
         * @param filename File where the PublicKey is saved
         * @return         The PublicKey get in the file
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws ClassNotFoundException
         * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
         * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
         */
        private static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromFile (String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
            try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
                BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) objectInputStream.readObject();
                BigInteger exponent = (BigInteger) objectInputStream.readObject();

                RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
                KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                return keyFactory.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get a PrivateKey from a file
         *
         * @param filename File where the PrivateKey is saved
         * @return         The PrivateKey get in the file
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws ClassNotFoundException
         * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
         * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
         */
        private static PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromFile (String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
            try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
                BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) objectInputStream.readObject();
                BigInteger exponent = (BigInteger) objectInputStream.readObject();

                RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
                KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                return keyFactory.generatePrivate(rsaPrivateKeySpec);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get the RSA keypair from the files
         *
         * @return The Keypair which contains the public and the private key
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws ClassNotFoundException
         * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
         * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
         */
        public static KeyPair getKeysFromFiles (String directorypath) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException{
            PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKeyFromFile(directorypath + "/public.key");
            PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKeyFromFile(directorypath + "/private.key");
            return new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EncryptionUtil encryptionUtil = null;

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Path of the keys :");
            String path = scanner.nextLine();

            try {
                encryptionUtil = new EncryptionUtil(EncryptionUtil.keyGenerate());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Path directorypath = Paths.get(path);
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(directorypath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                saveKeyPair(encryptionUtil, path);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException| IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error during the storage of the keys : " + e);
            }

            // Crypt part
            byte[] uncrypt;
            try {
                if (encryptionUtil != null) {
                    if (encryptionUtil.publicKey != null && encryptionUtil.privateKey != null) {
                        //Cryptage
                        byte[] crypt = encryption(Paths.get("filetocrypt"), encryptionUtil);

                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("cryptedfile");
                        FileChannel channel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
                        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(crypt.length * 2);
                        byteBuffer.put(crypt);
                        byteBuffer.flip();
                        channel.write(byteBuffer);
                        channel.close();

                        //Decryptage
                        uncrypt = decryption(Paths.get("cryptedfile"), encryptionUtil);

                        String v = new String(uncrypt);
                        System.out.println("END " + v);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
                    | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                    | BadPaddingException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I read that issue often comes when the wrong privatekey is used to decrypt or the Cypher is misused.
But i don't think it's the case here, or i didn't see it...
I have no clue about what is wrong with my code.
To run this code, you need a file called "filetocrypt".
I use bytes[] and I split them to crypt and decrypt the files, to dodge the size of bytes issue of RSA. This splitting works fine (I tried on files with Strings without using RSA algorithm)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: NIO always confuses me... Why is there a `byteBuffer.flip()` towards the end of your code?

Comment: I have to use Nio, i have no choice. I'm not allowed to use java.io.File.

I use flip() to prepare the sequence of channel write.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're decrypt code needs to be different from your encrypt code. There are a number of problems, but the one causing your error is as follows. Because of RSA padding, your input blocks are 200 bytes and your output blocks are 256 bytes. So, upon decryption, you need to read 256 bytes at a time and expect to get 200 bytes out. Instead, you are only reading 200 bytes at a time.

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.interfaces.*;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class RsaToy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        RSAPublicKey pub = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey priv = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();


        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pub);

        byte [] plain = new byte[100]; // initialize to all zero bytes

        // First encrypt: length of input (plain) is 100

        byte [] cipher = c.doFinal(plain);

        System.out.println("length of cipher is " + cipher.length);

        // Now decrypt: length of input(cipher) is 128;

        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, priv);

        byte [] decrypted_cipher = c.doFinal(cipher);

        System.out.println("length of decrypted cipher is " + decrypted_cipher.length);
    }
}
```

So, in your decryption method, change the 200 that appears in 3?? places to 256. You really shouldn't be hardcoding these constants.

Comment: I think I see what you mean but I have no idea on how I can repair it.
Do i have to use a buffer when I write in the files and when I read in the files?
Because of the RSA padding and the Cypher using, I can't use more a 245 bytes block... so how can I reach 256 bytes?
Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1936969: No, you must understand the decrypt and encrypt directions are completely different. On encrypt, the *input* block is at most (256 - 11) and the *output* is always 256 bytes. On decrypt, the *input* is always 256 bytes and the *output* is the length of the original plaintext.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand.
The output length of the decryption is the same as the input for the encrytion?
I still don't really see how the input of the decryption can be 256 bytes, because it's when I use 
    return cipher.doFinal(crypteddata);
that the exception is thrown...
And I don't see where I have to apply this...sorry

Comment: Can you try, in your `rsaEncryption()` method, to immediately reinitialize your cipher for decryption (`cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)`) and compare the result with your original plain text (use `Arrays.equals(byte[], byte[]`).

Comment: @user1936969: I'll add a very small example.

Comment: To GregS : I finally got it! It took me 4 days to got it... Very nice example GregS, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "NoPadding" :

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
```

or use Initialization Vector (IV) described in article :

https://www.baeldung.com/java-encryption-iv