# CipherInputStream gets BadPaddingException

Tags: java, encryption, badpaddingexception

Hope someone can see my issue.  I'm trying to send encrypted data over the network using `CipherOutputStream/CipherInputStream` and keep on getting `BadPaddingException`.  I use the same RSA keys for both sides and can manually encrypt/decrypt fine.  The modulus for both private and public keys match.

This is the working example that manually encrypt/decrypt using `Cipher` and the keys.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintStream out = System.out;
    try {
        PrivateKey pri_key = Util.readPrivateKey("data/private.der");
        PublicKey pub_key = Util.readPublicKey("data/public.der");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");

        String hi = "Hello World";
        byte[] data = hi.getBytes("UTF8");
        out.println("data[" + data.length + "]");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pub_key);
        byte[] encdata = cipher.doFinal(data);
        out.println("encdata[" + encdata.length + "]");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pri_key);
        byte[] decdata = cipher.doFinal(encdata);
        out.println("decdata[" + decdata.length + "]");
        out.println(new String(decdata, "UTF8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**The send/receive codes that does the encrypt/decrypt**

```java
static class ByteEncComm extends Comm {
    public ByteEncComm(Socket sock, PrivateKey priv_key, PublicKey pub_key) {
        super(sock, priv_key, pub_key);
    }

    public void send(Bird b) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, public_key);

            byte[] data = "Hello World".getBytes("UTF8");
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream(), cipher);
            cos.write(data, 0, data.length);
            cos.flush();
            out.println("Sent data[" + data.length + "]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Bird receive() {
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, private_key);

            CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(sock.getInputStream(), cipher);
            out.println("Avail " + cis.available());
            byte[] data = cis.readAllBytes();
            out.println("Got data[" + data.length + "]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Client Code:**

```java
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        try {
            PrivateKey pri_key = Util.readPrivateKey("data/private.der");
            PublicKey pub_key = Util.readPublicKey("data/public.der");

            Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);

            Comm comm = new Comm.ByteEncComm(sock, pri_key, pub_key);
            comm.send(new Bird("Robin"));

            sock.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server code:**

```java
public class Server extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        try {
            PrivateKey pri_key = Util.readPrivateKey("data/private.der");
            PublicKey pub_key = Util.readPublicKey("data/public.der");

            ServerSocket serversock = new ServerSocket(5555);
            Socket sock = serversock.accept();

            Comm comm = new Comm.ByteEncComm(sock, pri_key, pub_key);
            comm.receive();

            sock.close();
            serversock.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:148)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:261)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:409)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readAllBytes(InputStream.java:346)
    at foo.enc.Comm$ByteEncComm.receive(Comm.java:139)
    at foo.enc.Server.main(Server.java:21)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadOAEP(RSAPadding.java:488)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:284)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:372)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:418)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2152)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:145)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BadPaddingException : Decryption error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944374/badpaddingexception-decryption-error)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I had read that posting before. My problem is I only get the error when sending over the net as an encrypted stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `CipherOutputStream`, you should take a look at the `close()` function, the function implicitly performs a `doFinal()` ([Source Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html#close())):

> Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream.
>
> **This method invokes the doFinal method of the encapsulated cipher object, which causes any bytes buffered by the encapsulated cipher to be processed.** The result is written out by calling the flush method of this output stream.
>
> This method resets the encapsulated cipher object to its initial state and calls the close method of the underlying output stream.

---

It may be better for you to simply make use of the basic `OutputStream` and `InputStream` if `CipherOutputStream` is not mandatory. The extra effort is to perform your encryption with `doFinal()` manually before you send it out.

Comment: Thanks for such a great response. That fixed it for this example.  I remember doing it in another example that uses `ObjectOutputStream` with `CipherOutputStream` and it didn't work. I probably messed up on which one I closed.

Comment: If I go with the manual effort, I assume I would need to prepend the data with the data size to assist in reading it on the receiving side?

Comment: Of course you can do so. But simply following your working example should do the work.