# javax.crypto.badpaddingexception decryption error unpadv15

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa, cryptdecrypt

After generating and encrypting a license file, I'm encountering a decryption error when trying to open the encrypted file. I've debugged the code and tried different padding types, but haven't been successful. The code block is provided below. What do you think could be the issue?

```
static ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator  = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance ("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair pair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    LicenseImportDTO licenseData = LicenseImportDTO.builder()
            .licenseKey ("123DS92-SAKH-SKH-22")
            .contact("WORLD A.Ş.")
            .customerName(DigestUtils.md5Hex("WORLD"))
            .cluster(false)
            .numberOfNodes(0)
            .numberOfSites(2)
            .duration(12)
            .licenseType(LicenseType.BASE)
            .deviceSize(DeviceSize.SMALL).build();

    String encrpyLicense = encryptExportLicenceDTO(licenseData,pair.getPublic());
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    readLicenseData(encrpyLicense,pair.getPrivate());
}

public static String encryptExportLicenceDTO(LicenseImportDTO licenceDTO, PublicKey publicKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, JsonProcessingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGen.init(128);
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = aesCipher.doFinal(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(licenceDTO).getBytes());
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] encryptedSymmetricKey = rsaCipher.doFinal(secretKey.getEncoded());
    byte[] combined = new byte[encryptedBytes.length + encryptedSymmetricKey.length];
    System.arraycopy(encryptedSymmetricKey, 0, combined, 0, encryptedSymmetricKey.length);
    System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes, 0, combined, encryptedSymmetricKey.length, encryptedBytes.length);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(combined);
}

private static LicenseImportDTO readLicenseData(String  encodedLicense , PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
    byte[] combined = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedLicense);
    byte[] encryptedSymmetricKey = new byte[128];
    byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[combined.length - 128];
    System.arraycopy(combined, 0, encryptedSymmetricKey, 0, 128);
    System.arraycopy(combined, 128, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.length);
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] symmetricKeyBytes = rsaCipher.doFinal(encryptedSymmetricKey);
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(symmetricKeyBytes, 0, symmetricKeyBytes.length, "AES");
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = aesCipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
    String decryptedJson = new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return objectMapper.readValue(decryptedJson, LicenseImportDTO.class);
}
```

I try everything but not fix this bug. My expecthing is read the license contents.

Comment: Your RSA modulus is 2048 bits in size, or 256 bytes. However, your decryption code assumes its 128 bytes. Once you fix this, your next error is that you are not initializing the AES decryption cipher with the IV used during encryption. You have to retrieve this IV from the encryptor with `aesCipher.getIV()` and provide it to the decryptor. You might as well use the more modern and secure OAEP padding for RSA, and GCM for the AES mode which gives you tamper detection for free.

Comment: In this case you could use an all zero IV as the AES key is always generated at random.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31946825/18157

Comment: Thank you so much, James and Marteen. You couldn't see the problem even though you were looking at the same place for a long time. My issue has been resolved.

Comment: You're welcome, although you wrote "couldn't" instead of "could" I think and it is Maarten with a double A, yes Dutch is weird. Free security advice: I'd at least use RSA-3072 for 128 bit security. As the AES key is wrapped and since multi-target attacks for AES are slightly a thing you could consider AES-256 instead of 128 (increase key size to 256 in the generator).